# Create variable name for table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I'm wondering if it is possible to create a variable name when copying a table to another.

Here's my sort-of algorithm/code

```
DECLARE @NewTableName VARCHAR(50)
SET @NewTableName = 'MyTable_'+GETDATE() --MyTable_12282010 (for example)

SELECT *
INTO @NewTableName
FROM MyTable
```

I'm wondering if this is possible. I tried it before, but it failed. Any suggestions guys?

Answer (score 4):

It is possible, but only using dynamic TSQL.

See [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)  (or the 2000 version [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933299%28v=sql.80%29.aspx))

Be aware of [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

Comment: is it applicable for sql server 2000?

Comment: @Musikero31: if this answer (or another) is helpful, please don't forget to mark it as 'Accepted'